# Why do the Weasleys have to de-gnome the garden at the Burrow?

Tags: harry-potter, character-motivation

Wouldn't it be possible to simply magically erect a gnome-proof fence around the garden?

The Weasleys collectively are fairly good wizards, both practical and theoretical. Hard to believe they could do all the other things shown in the series but can't conjure up a decent fence.

Comment: Who's to say gnomes don't have magic that would let them get through a fence?

Comment: Mrs. Weasley had learnt de-gnoming from the best authority: Lockhart's books.  If a gnome-proof magical fence was possible, then surely Lockhart would have mentioned that in the books.

Comment: If you have several active children who are likely to manage to get into mischief if they aren't kept busy, you generally find them something to do. De-gnoming the garden seems like a good job - active, keeps them within the garden, slight element of risk to make it not boring - Molly Weasley is a very smart woman!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Mr. Weasley is soft on the garden gnomes because he thinks they're funny and keeps letting them return. I'm sure the Weasleys could conjure a magical fence that would keep the gnomes out, but apparently Mr. Weasley likes them too much to completely displace them.

The Weasleys could also keep a Jarvey in the garden. Jarveys eat gnomes. I have a feeling Mr. Weasley would *really* object to that method of gnome control.

Comment: Knowing Mrs. Weasley, I can somehow easily see her looking darkly at Arthur and him easily conceding that the fence is, indeed, a good idea. Bute yeah, I can't think of ANY other canon info to explain this, so +1 and accept.

Comment: @Slytherincess: Hmmm...I like this answer, but it needs to be fleshed out more.  Add a few paragraphs, then we'll talk ;-)

Comment: @Jeff - I concede. This MUST have been written by an impostor

Comment: @DVK Nah, I could see Mr. Weasley rapidly shifting the subject away from his gnome pals in some altogether unconvincing but very effective way.