# Why don't Muggles have to de-gnomify their gardens?

Tags: harry-potter, magical-creatures

The question "[Why do the Weasleys have to de-gnome the garden at the Burrow?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/8646/51085)" is focused on why magic isn't used to get rid of garden gnomes.
I've begun to wonder why muggles don't deal with gnomes.

[image: Harry Potter and Ronald Weasley De-gnoming the yard at The Burrow.]

- Are garden gnomes only visible to wizards?
- Are garden gnomes do any harm?
- If garden gnomes are invisible and harmless, why to degnomify a garden at all?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

According to JKR, gnomes are only found in the homes of wizards. No specific explanation is given as to why this is.

> **Q.** *Why are the gnomes bad? What do they do?*
>
> **JKR:** *Gnomes eat the roots of your plants, and make little heaps of earth, like moles do. They are also a bit of a giveaway that
>   wizards live in a house.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Scholastic: Interview With J. K. Rowling](http://www.scholastic.com/teachers/article/interview-j-k-rowling)</sup></sub>

As to their *other detrimental effects*, the Wiki description of the [Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone video game](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Gnome) indicates that in large numbers, the gnomes can become emboldened and quite vicious

> **Rolanda Hooch:** *"No flying today, Mr Potter. There are gnomes burrowing into the pitch."*
>
> **Harry Potter:** *"Why would that stop anyone flying?"*
>
> **Rolanda Hooch:** *"Have you tried to land a broomstick with fifteen gnomes snapping at your ankles? I thought not. Run along now."*

Comment: Is there a reason as to why wizards wouldn't want to give away that they live in a house? It's not like a muggle would know to look out for a wizard's house.

Comment: @Edlothiad - A weird, and highly noticeable magical creature hanging around in your garden? That's not the sort of thing you'd want your muggle neighbours to notice.

Comment: I didn't realise they were highly noticeable, that does make sense then. Cheers

Comment: @Edlothiad - They're a foot high and swear a lot.

Comment: @Valorum: So basically, they're Nac Mac Feegle